# Why isn't my method printing what I want it to whenever I call it?

Tags: c#, methods

I am very much a beginner at C# and for some reason, my method is not doing what I want it to.

The method I am referring to is the Roll() method. I want it to print the class name and all of the students in the class list whenever I call the method. It doesn't do any of that. All it does is print "Roster:", leaving out the things I want it to print. Am I missing something? How can I fix this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    Course Astronomy = new Course("115", "Astronomy", "Allen");
    Astronomy.StudentList.Add(new Student("Mark", "Johnson", 94.6));
    Astronomy.StudentList.Add(new Student("Marcy", "Steinfield", 89.2));
    Astronomy.StudentList.Add(new Student("Jennifer", "Fox", 98.7));
    Astronomy.StudentList.Add(new Student("Cody", "Fields", 84.3));
    Astronomy.StudentList.Add(new Student("Blake", "Patterson", 78.4));
    Astronomy.StudentList.Add(new Student("Brittany", "Cox", 91.8));
    Astronomy.StudentList.Add(new Student("Paul", "Sims", 90.0));
    Astronomy.roll();
  }
}
public class Student {
    
  public string fname;
  public string lname;
  public int avg;
  public Student() {
  }
  public Student(string fname, string lname, double avg) {
    fname = fname;
    lname = lname;
    avg = avg;
  }
}
public class Course {
  public List<Student> StudentList = new List<Student>();
  public string ccode;
  public string cname;
  public string teacher;
  
  public Course() {
  }
  public Course(string ccode, string cname, string teacher) {
    ccode = ccode;
    cname = cname;
    teacher = teacher;
  }
  public object addStudent(object sdnt) {

    return sdnt;
  }
  public void roll() {
    Console.WriteLine($"{cname} {ccode} Roster:\n");
    foreach(var student in StudentList) {
      Console.WriteLine($"{student.fname}\n");
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Roster:
```

Comment: Ask yourself what `addStudent` does, and what you _want_ it to do.

Comment: BTW your code as is does work - it is just that you haven't set any of the students fname properties. This is because `fname = fname;` should be `this.fname = fname;` https://dotnetfiddle.net/FbQhTj

Comment: ```a.cs(25,5): warning CS1717: Assignment made to same variable; did you mean to assign something else?
a.cs(26,5): warning CS1717: Assignment made to same variable; did you mean to assign something else?
a.cs(27,5): warning CS1717: Assignment made to same variable; did you mean to assign something else?
a.cs(39,5): warning CS1717: Assignment made to same variable; did you mean to assign something else?
a.cs(40,5): warning CS1717: Assignment made to same variable; did you mean to assign something else?
a.cs(41,5): ...```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code that work:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    Course Astronomy = new Course("115", "Astronomy", "Allen");
    Astronomy.StudentList.Add(new Student("Mark", "Johnson", 94.6));
    Astronomy.StudentList.Add(new Student("Marcy", "Steinfield", 89.2));
    Astronomy.StudentList.Add(new Student("Jennifer", "Fox", 98.7));
    Astronomy.StudentList.Add(new Student("Cody", "Fields", 84.3));
    Astronomy.StudentList.Add(new Student("Blake", "Patterson", 78.4));
    Astronomy.StudentList.Add(new Student("Brittany", "Cox", 91.8));
    Astronomy.StudentList.Add(new Student("Paul", "Sims", 90.0));
    Astronomy.roll();
  }
}
public class Student {

  public string fname;
  public string lname;
  public double avg;
  public Student() {
  }
  public Student(string fname, string lname, double avg) {
    this.fname = fname;
    this.lname = lname;
    this.avg = avg;
  }
}
public class Course {
  public List<Student> StudentList = new List<Student>();
  public string ccode;
  public string cname;
  public string teacher;

  public Course() {
  }
  public Course(string ccode, string cname, string teacher) {
    this.ccode = ccode;
    this.cname = cname;
    this.teacher = teacher;
  }
  public void roll() {
    Console.WriteLine($"{cname} {ccode} Roster:\n");
    foreach(var student in StudentList) {
      Console.WriteLine($"{student.fname}\n");
    }
  }
}
```

What's changed:

- in each constructor, instead of calling `ccode = ccode;` I change it to `this.ccode = ccode;`.

  - This means that data member `this.ccode` is assigned value from `ccode` constructor parameter.
  - While your old code `ccode = ccode;` means that constructor parameter `ccode` is assigned value from `ccode` constructor parameter
- As pointed out by @mjwills, I removed misleading `addStudent` method/function that didn't do anything

The hint is already provided in compiler's error message:

```
$ csc a.cs 
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 3.6.0-4.20224.5 (ec77c100)
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

a.cs(25,5): warning CS1717: Assignment made to same variable; did you mean to assign something else?
a.cs(26,5): warning CS1717: Assignment made to same variable; did you mean to assign something else?
a.cs(27,5): warning CS1717: Assignment made to same variable; did you mean to assign something else?
a.cs(39,5): warning CS1717: Assignment made to same variable; did you mean to assign something else?
a.cs(40,5): warning CS1717: Assignment made to same variable; did you mean to assign something else?
a.cs(41,5): warning CS1717: Assignment made to same variable; did you mean to assign something else?
```

Here, the compiler said that you're assigning a value from a variable to itself: `Assignment made to same variable; did you mean to assign something else?`. It's done on line 25,26,27,39,40,41, which is:

```
    fname = fname;
    lname = lname;
    avg = avg;
    ccode = ccode;
    cname = cname;
    teacher = teacher;
```

Output:

```
$ mono a.exe 
Astronomy 115 Roster:

Mark

Marcy

Jennifer

Cody

Blake

Brittany

Paul
```

Comment: Please remove the misleading `addStudent`. Or make the list `private` and have `addStudent` actually do its job.

Comment: @mjwills oops, I didn't notice it since I just copy-pasted and fixed where I need to fix to make it output the expected string

Comment: Thank you for the help! I feel kind of stupid for not seeing that but programming is such a trial and error type learning process. Sidenote: This is an assignment for a class and I was supposed to "Provide a method called addStudent that accepts one Student parameter" and I didn't really know what that meant, so I just made addStudent() method and was gonna come back to it.

Comment: isn't it just ```public object addStudent(object sdnt) { this.StudentList.Add(sdnt) } ```?

Comment: Maybe. I don't know, I feel like the list I made for the students serves about the same purpose as that method would- keeping track of all of the students added. I feel like the addStudent() method is not really necessary if I use the StudentList instead.

Comment: @Jerry The advantage of `AddStudent` is it allows you to make the list private. With the code as is, nothing stops me from removing students (for example) from that list.